# Unable to deploy project to google app engine

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

When i try to deploy my project from eclipse to Google app engine  eclipse will prompt web brower to login to Google after login it only shows Deploying to Google app engine requires authentication  after that nothing will happen please any help me to sort this problem

Am using Java 7
eclipse indigo 7.3 and google plugins

[image: Error Page]

Comment: can you suggest me the steps to Deploy project in Google app engine using command prompt

Answer (score 2):

Try to sign into your Google account in Eclipse before deploying. Hit "Sign into Google" button at the lower right corner of Eclipse.

Comment: I Tried it but same iam facing the same issue ,when i click sign into google button it ask for user name and password after that same error appers

Comment: Can you deploy without Eclipse?

Comment: can you suggest me the steps to Deploy project in Google app engine using command prompt

Comment: You got any solution to sign in ?

Comment: You got any solution please ?